# CMake Error: /catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake returned error code No such file or directory

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to do catkin_make with python3 on Arch Linux, but I get this error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/home/oskar/workspace/catkin_ws/build/python3
  "/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
  "/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
  "/home/oskar/workspace/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code No such file or directory
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:74 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:167 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:56 (find_package)
```

Can anyone please help me solving this issue, seems some part of catkin wasn't generated before.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323149/cmake-error:-/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake---returned-error-code-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [bionade24](https://answers.ros.org/users/41535/bionade24/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2019-05-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-14**:
can you check which of those files doesn't exist?

`/home/oskar/workspace/catkin_ws/build/python3` seems suspicious to me: do you have a `python3` binary in `/home/oskar/workspace/catkin_ws/build`?

**Comment by [bionade24](https://answers.ros.org/users/41535/bionade24/) on 2019-05-14**:
The file pacakge.cmake doesn't exist. And since `catkin_make` never finished successfully, there neither a py3 nor py2 binary in the folder. I always used this catkin flag: `catkin_make  --cmake-args -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=python3`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-14**:
So this `/home/oskar/workspace/catkin_ws/build/python3` exists?

But `/home/oskar/workspace/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake` doesn't?

**Comment by [bionade24](https://answers.ros.org/users/41535/bionade24/) on 2019-05-14**:
None of both files exist.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-14**:
Then I would assume the immediate problem is `/home/oskar/workspace/catkin_ws/build/python3`. `/home/oskar/workspace/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake` is a later problem.

**Comment by [bionade24](https://answers.ros.org/users/41535/bionade24/) on 2019-05-14**:
Do you know which package is mandatory for the python executable?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-14**:
I don't understand your question.

`python3` should probably be provided by your OS.

The issue may be that for some reason, the CMake macros/functions are expecting a `python3` binary/link to be present in the `build` space. That may be perfectly normal for Catkin to do, I don't know. I doubt it though.

**Comment by [bionade24](https://answers.ros.org/users/41535/bionade24/) on 2019-05-14**:
So I'll do a little bit research tomorrow trough cmake's python linking. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it by specifiying the interpreter value with the full path. Before, I used `catkin_make  --cmake-args -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=python3` and then changed it to `catkin_make  --cmake-args -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3` Now it seems working.

---

Originally posted by [bionade24](https://answers.ros.org/users/41535/bionade24/) with karma: 33 on 2019-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-15**:
The full path seems to be used in other Q&As with similar subjects as well (and in the `catkin_tools` documentation, [here](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html#controlling-python-version) fi), so that is probably required.

It might be enough (and more robust / portable) to set the `PYTHON_VERSION` though. See #q114801 fi.